# Use common datatable for multiple gridviews

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I have bootstrap tabs and each tab pane contains a grid. 
My requirement is to use one data table for all these grid view by filtering on DataView.
Once user select a tab it will filter all rows with one condition and shows data.
Is it possible to do this?

```
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="all">
                <asp:GridView ID="gridViewAll" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="design">
                <asp:GridView ID="gridViewDesign" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="manufacture">
                <asp:GridView ID="gridViewManufacture" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: on page load store data in session and then tab click event to load  data from session to gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used DataView for each grid view and set the filter according to the grid.